# How do I use this build tool (errorprone) in release builds only?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, errorprone

I'm using a code analysis tool called "errorprone" in my builds. It runs for every release type, but I'd like to only use it for release builds (or more specifically, non-debug builds). The relevant parts of my gradle config look like this:

```
plugins {
    id "net.ltgt.errorprone" version "0.0.14"
}
```

...

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += [
            '-Xep:DefaultCharset:OFF',
}
```

...

```
dependencies {
    errorprone 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:2.3.1'
}
```

I've already configured `buildTypes` for `debug` and `release`. How do I configure errorprone dependency to only use `release`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Barry, Add your dependency as 

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
android.productFlavors.each {
        flavor ->
            if (flavor.name.contains("debug")) {
                implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.4'
                // add("ReleaseImplementation", ('com.android.support:leanback-v17:' + supportLibraryVersion))
                //add("${flavor.name}DebugImplementation", (fileTree(include: 'vgdrm.jar', dir: "${vgdrmRootDir}/${flavor.ext.vgdrmVersion}-debug")))
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. I still see errorprone running in my debug build.
(btw I changed "if(flavor" to "if(!flavor" since I only want it in non-debug builds.)